# Displaying a RoR app/page in an external html page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was wondering if anyone can help me with the following problem:
I have a external (and normal) html page that uses javascript to display other html
files in an object tag. These files are in the same directory, so theres no problem there.
How can I link and display my Ruby on Rails application/pages in this same object tag and
html file? i.e. How do I integrate the two?

Thanx

These are the elements which send the data over and the object that displays the page:

```
<div id = "leftBar">
    <div>
        <nav>
        <ul type="square">
            <li>
                    <a id = "menuLink" href = "Page.html" onclick="loadPage(this); return false;">Solar Flare
                    </a>
                </li>

    </nav>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div id = "mainPage">
     <object id = "obj" type = "text/html" data= "Main.html"> </object>
 </div>
```

This is the JavaScript function that displays the page in the object tag:

```
function loadPage(link)
{
    document.getElementById("obj").data = link.href;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how you currently do this?

Answer (score 1):

Ruby on Rails can only be run at a server. Before you can access the pages inside a Rails project, you need to start such a server on localhost or deploy your application to a webserver. For example, in a Rails 3 project, you can start a server with:

```
rails server
```

To access the pages inside a Rails project, just point to `http://localhost:3000`:

```
<a id="menuLink" href="http://localhost:3000" onclick="loadPage(this); return false;">Your Rails project</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems weird to me. Maybe you can explain a little more what you want to achieve.

In the meantime: if your Rails application is up an running anywhere on a server then you can access it like any other link. And if you want to embedd any page (no matter if Rails, PHP or a plain HTML page) you could use for example the iframe tag.